# Visual Studio and Entity Framework edmx: My Custom edits are over-written

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, edmx

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, Entity Framework 4, and model-first development.
I modelled in the VS EDM designer, then custom edited my edmx file so that the table names are uppercase (not my choice, DBA requirement on name-case-sensitive database).
i.e. an edmx ssdl entry will look like:

```
<EntitySet Name="MESSAGES" EntityType="SIMPLEPIX.STORE.MESSAGES" store:Type="Tables" Schema="MW_ARCHIVE" Table="MESSAGES" />
```

I then right-click in the designer to "Generate Database from Model..."
This does 2 things.  First it reverts all my edmx edits back to camel case.  I.e. the line above becomes:

```
<EntitySet Name="Messages" EntityType="SimplePix.Store.Messages" store:Type="Tables" Schema="MW_ARCHIVE" />
```

(and note my *Table="MESSAGES"* attribute has been removed).

Second it creates the following DDL:

```
[snip]
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[MW_ARCHIVE].[MESSAGES]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [MW_ARCHIVE].[MESSAGES];
[snip]
CREATE TABLE [MW_ARCHIVE].[Messages] (
[snip]
```

That's right: it knows it has to drop MESSAGES (uppercase), but then wants to create Messages (camel case).

How can I get VS to leave my edmx edits alone and generate the correct (uppercase) DDL?  Thanks very.

Comment: Have you ever found a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can't modify the EF generated classes as they will be changed everytime you do the "Generate from database model". I do not think there is a way around this.

Comment: Thanks for commenting.  As I think the question makes clear, it's not the generated classes (code) that are an issue, it's the generated DDL and SSDL (database naming) sections.

Answer (score 0):

It says this at the top of your POCO classes (if that's what you're using

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Whenever you regenerate your code any changes you made will be overwritten, **every time** without fail

I'm not saying it cannot be done through some obscure methods or tool, but none that I personally am aware of.

If you're tables have to be uppercase why not make then uppercase on the DB server? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Same commment as the one for stephen776 I'm afraid: thanks for responding, but it's not the generated classes (code) that are an issue, it's the generated DDL and SSDL (database naming) sections.  You are describing a _database-first_ approach, but I am using _model-first_, that means EF is generating the script to create the database tables.